# Dijkstra's Algorithm printing too much

Tags: python, printing, dijkstra, sys

So I have this code here, which take a graph and then prints the shortest distance between two points chosen. The input for it is python filename.py start end map.txt
It works great with graphs I've given it such as this one:

```
{'a': {'b': 5, 'c': 8},
'b': {'a': 5, 'd': 6},
'c': {'a': 8, 'd': 2},
'd': {'b': 6, 'c': 2, 'e': 12, 'f': 2},
'e': {'d': 12, 'g': 3},
'f': {'d': 2, 'g': 7},
'g': {'e': 3, 'f':7}}
```

The only problem is that when it prints output in the Command, it prints it like this:
Distance from start to end is (distance , [start,end])
I can't figure out how tot make it just print the distance without any of the parentheses or the start and end point. Any help is appreciated.
     """
        Winter 2014
        Authors: Cole Charbonneau & Peter Pham
        Credit: [Python: Importing a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628503/python-importing-a-graph?noredirect=1)
            Stackoverflow for helping us figure out how to import a graph via sys.argv

```
    Finds the shortest path between two points in a dictionary graph.
    Uses a single-source shortest distance approach, nearly identical to
        Dijkstra's Algortihm.

    Takes input in the format: python filename.py start end grap.txt
    """
    import sys

    def shortestpath(graph,start,end,visited=[],distances={},predecessors={}):
        """Finds the shortest path between a start and end point from a graph"""

        if start==end:
            path=[]                             ##If the starting point is the end point, then we're done

            while end != None:
                path.append(end)
                end=predecessors.get(end,None)

            return distances[start], path[::-1]
                                                ##Check if it's the first time through it, and set current distance to 0
        if not visited: distances[start]=0
                                                ##Runs through each adjacent point, and keeps track of the preceeding ones
        for neighbor in graph[start]:

            if neighbor not in visited:
                neighbordist = distances.get(neighbor,sys.maxsize)
                tentativedist = distances[start] + graph[start][neighbor]

                if tentativedist < neighbordist:
                    distances[neighbor] = tentativedist
                    predecessors[neighbor]=start
                                                ##Now that all of the adjacent points are visited, we can mark the current point as visited
        visited.append(start)
                                                ##This finds the next closest unvisited point to start on
        unvisiteds = dict((k, distances.get(k,sys.maxsize)) for k in graph if k not in visited)
        closestvertex = min(unvisiteds, key=unvisiteds.get)
                                                ##Recurses that closest point making it the current one
        return shortestpath(graph,closestvertex,end,visited,distances,predecessors)




    if __name__ == "__main__":
        start = sys.argv[1]
        end = sys.argv[2]
        graph = eval(open(sys.argv[3],'r').read())
        if len(sys.argv) != 4:
            print('Input syntax: python filename.py start end map.py')
        else:
            print('Distance from ',start,' to ',end,' is ',shortestpath(graph,start,end))


        """
        Result:
            (20, ['a', 'y', 'w', 'b'])
            """
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is returning a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), so you need to either access the first element in the tuple

```
length = shortestpath(graph,start,end)[0]
```

or unpack it:

```
length, path = shortestpath(graph,start,end)
```